# Compiler printing out wrong answer- Java

Tags: java

I had to make a code that defines how do basic math operations with complex numbers. I made one class to define how to do these operations and a test class to run the code.

Here is the code to define the operation:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ComplexNumber{

    float real;
    float imaginary;
    private float a;
    private float b;

public ComplexNumber(float a, float b){
    real = a;
    imaginary = b;
}

public ComplexNumber add(ComplexNumber otherNumber){
    ComplexNumber newComplex;
    float newA = a + otherNumber.getA();
    float newB = b + otherNumber.getB();
    newComplex = new ComplexNumber(newA, newB);
    return newComplex;
}

public ComplexNumber minus(ComplexNumber otherNumber){
    ComplexNumber newComplex;
    float newA = a - otherNumber.getA();
    float newB = b - otherNumber.getB();
    newComplex = new ComplexNumber(newA, newB);
    return newComplex;
}

public ComplexNumber times(ComplexNumber otherNumber){
    ComplexNumber newComplex;
    float newA = (a * otherNumber.getA()) - (b * otherNumber.getB());
    float newB = (b * otherNumber.getB()) - (a * otherNumber.getA());
    newComplex = new ComplexNumber(newA, newB);
    return newComplex;
}

public ComplexNumber divide(ComplexNumber otherNumber){
    ComplexNumber newComplex;
    float newA = (a * otherNumber.getA()) + (b*otherNumber.getB());
    float newB = (otherNumber.getA() * otherNumber.getA()) + (otherNumber.getB() * otherNumber.getB());
    float newC = (b * otherNumber.getA()) + (a * otherNumber.getB());
    float newD = (otherNumber.getA() * otherNumber.getA()) + (otherNumber.getB() * otherNumber.getB()); 
    float firstFraction = (newA / newB);
    float secondFraction = (newC / newD);
    newComplex = new ComplexNumber(firstFraction, secondFraction);
    return newComplex;      
}

public float getA(){
    return a;
}

public float getB(){
    return b;
}

public String toString(){
    return a + " + " + b + "i";
 }
}
```

Here is the test class that I have:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class ComplexCalculator{
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    float tempA, tempB, tempC, tempD;
    ComplexNumber first, second, result;

    System.out.println("Choose an operation: \n1. Addition \n2. Subtraction \n3. Multiplication \n4. Division \n5. Quit");
    int selection = myScanner.nextInt();

    if (selection == 1) {
        System.out.println("Enter A: ");
        tempA = myScanner.nextFloat();
        System.out.println("Enter B: ");
        tempB = myScanner.nextFloat();
        System.out.println("Enter C: ");
        tempC = myScanner.nextFloat();
        System.out.println("Enter D: ");
        tempD = myScanner.nextFloat();

        first = new ComplexNumber(tempA, tempB);
        second = new ComplexNumber(tempC, tempD);
        result = first.add(second);
        System.out.println(result.toString());
    }

    if (selection == 2) {
        System.out.println("Enter A: ");
        tempA = myScanner.nextFloat();
        System.out.println("Enter B: ");
        tempB = myScanner.nextFloat();
        System.out.println("Enter C: ");
        tempC = myScanner.nextFloat();
        System.out.println("Enter D: ");
        tempD = myScanner.nextFloat();

        first = new ComplexNumber(tempA, tempB);
        second = new ComplexNumber(tempC, tempD);
        result = first.minus(second);
        System.out.println(result.toString());
    }

    if (selection == 3) {
        System.out.println("Enter A: ");
        tempA = myScanner.nextFloat();
        System.out.println("Enter B: ");
        tempB = myScanner.nextFloat();
        System.out.println("Enter C: ");
        tempC = myScanner.nextFloat();
        System.out.println("Enter D: ");
        tempD = myScanner.nextFloat();

        first = new ComplexNumber(tempA, tempB);
        second = new ComplexNumber(tempC, tempD);
        result = first.times(second);
        System.out.println(result.toString());
    }

    if (selection == 4) {
        System.out.println("Enter A: ");
        tempA = myScanner.nextFloat();
        System.out.println("Enter B: ");
        tempB = myScanner.nextFloat();
        System.out.println("Enter C: ");
        tempC = myScanner.nextFloat();
        System.out.println("Enter D: ");
        tempD = myScanner.nextFloat();

        first = new ComplexNumber(tempA, tempB);
        second = new ComplexNumber(tempC, tempD);
        result = first.divide(second);
        System.out.println(result.toString());
    }

    if (selection == 5){
        System.out.println("Thank you!");
        return;
    }

}
}
```

Whenever I run my code, I put in the four numbers, but it always prints out `0.0 + 0.0i`.

Comment: This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

Comment: What is the purpose of `float a; float b;` when you already have `float real; float imaginary;`?

Comment: So, what have you done to debug it?  Have you printed out the values of tempA, tempB, tempC, tempD even?

Comment: (By the way, the compiler doesn't print answers.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue occurs as you have specified two members

```
private float a;
private float b;
```

and your `toString()` is defined as

```
public String toString(){
    return a + " + " + b + "i";
}
```

Yet there is nowhere in your code that either `a` or `b` has been set.

Try replacing a and b with `real` and `imaginary`.